# Panel only showing on specific page

Tags: javascript, location, document, if-statement

I need a working javascript code which shows a certain panel only on one specific page on my website and hides it on the rest. It's a forum-esque setup.

Here's what I got so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowPanel()
{
if(document.location.href == "http://www.exampleurl.com")
{document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";}
else
{document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "none";}
}

</script>

        <div id="panel" onload="ShowPanel">
            Example text.
        </div>
```

According to the example code I've looked up, all of this seems to be reasonable, but obviously there's an error somewhere. Nothing happens.

Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the onload event cannot be used on a DIV element. onload can only be used on the document body or an external resource (iframe, image, scripts).

Your best bet is to place your JavaScript at the bottom of the page instead.

e.g.

```
<div id="panel">
    Example text.
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
if(document.location.href == "http://www.exampleurl.com"){
    document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "none";
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this might actually be the issue. I'm currently looking for the right location to place and invoke the script; placing it at the bottom yielded no success.
I'm going to contact the forum service devs for support on this one.

Comment: Indeed, consider this problem solved. The forum operates without functions and invoke lines. It's odd, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the `document.location.href` really is on the page by typing it into your console (<kbd>F12</kbd>, usually). For instance, most browsers will add the trailing slash onto a server name even if there isn't one in the URL. The match has to be exact for your code to work as written.

Another options is to compare `document.location.pathname`, which will have everything after the server name. If you want to make a case insensitive compare, you can use  `document.location.pathname.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thank you, that doesn't appear to be the problem, though. If the URL was specified wrong, the panel would just hide on all pages, which it doesn't. It still displays.

Comment: @TW_ Grant Clement's answer seems right... you can make sure your code is running at all by putting in something like `alert(1);`—if you don't get this your code isn't being run.

Comment: Using the alert test has proven to be very useful!